# Open Excel(xlsb) file In client browser

Tags: .net, excel

I have a calculator built in excel, there are buttons labels and corresponding code to calculate premium based on user input. I want to display this excel in browser so that user can use it online.

Since the calculator is complex if I can do this, it will save lot of development time.

> its an xlsb file.

Any idea how this can be done.

Comment: http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244

Answer (score 0):

Could you convert it to a [google doc](http://docs.google.com) then embed it?

Edit: Just realised, if you have buttons with code behind this will not work, do you have code behind the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Three strategies:

- load the Excel workbook into an <iframe>
- load it into a new browser window
- load it in a [jQuery modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: I want to open it in the browser window so that he can calculate online, where with your solution it gives him an option to save rather than using it in the browser itself.